# SSIS Package Data Flow Query Not Updating in SQL Agent Job

Tags: mysql, ssis, etl, sql-agent-job

I have an SSIS job that grabs data from MySQL (ODBC) via a raw query and moves it to a SQL Server destination table. I deployed this job to SQL Agent and it has worked fine.

Recently, I made a change to the query. Specifically, instead of grabbing a unixtime string field from the source table, I now translate it into a date using FROM_UNIXTIME in MySQL. So something like 160913058 will now come in as Jan 7, 2023

I tested the job in Visual Studio successfully and redeployed to SQL Agent. However, when I run from SQL Agent it is still passing the old unix time string instead of the new datetime. Seems like it just doesn't want to update itself, although the new query is right there in SSIS and works when I execute the package manually.

Any thoughts on this? I know SSIS and SQL Agent can be wonky, but this is a new one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gonna leave this question up in case it helps someone else, BUT - the answer was that I was deploying to the wrong Integration Services Catalog

I deployed the "new version" of the packages to catalog "ABC2" and the SQL Agent job was actually pointing to "ABC1"... so that's why the "old version" of the packages was the one executing.

This was resolved after re-deploying the solution to the right directory.